# Resample Pandas dataframe not valid

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I try to import a .csv 30-minutes-timeseries file with pandas to resample it to hours but the resample function doesn't recognise the datetime format.

1. Import works correct with a script found on stackoverflow.
2. When I open the Dataframe and double-click on a date+time it mentions that I can't edit a Timestamp.
3. When I try te resample the DataFrame it gives the **TypeError: 'Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex''**

Below is the code that I'm currently using, the date and time are separated columns in the .csv file and merged by the script into 'datetime'. The .csv consists of 8 columns and 5131 rows.

```
def dateparse(d,t):
    dt = d + " " + t
    return pd.datetime.strptime(dt, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv(infile, parse_dates={'datetime': ['date', 'time']}, date_parser=dateparse)

df.resample('H').mean()
```

Anyone familiair with this problem?

Comment: The error is telling you that you can only use `resample` with a `datetimeindex` so you need to set your index to such a column first

Comment: you can also do `df.resample('H', on='datetime').mean()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the index of the dataframe to the `datetime` column first, convert it to a datetime index, and it should work.

```
def dateparse(d,t):
    dt = d + " " + t
    return pd.datetime.strptime(dt, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df = pd.read_csv(infile, parse_dates={'datetime': ['date', 'time']}, date_parser=dateparse)

df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.resample('H').mean()
```